# How to tell Ignore JSON to ignore property name not the response in it

Tags: java, json, jackson

My Json response coming as below. DisplayDemo class contain object view where all the transaction are getting added. I want to display my json object **with out view tag**. Any suggestion on this experts ?

```
{
    "view": { // dont want to show view in output 
        "transaction": [
            {           
                "status": "Delivered",
                "reason": "XXX",
            }
        ]
    }
}

public class DisplayDemo {
   private DisplayDemo view;  // transaction result will be added in view 
   //getter and setter of view 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html). Something like

```
public class DisplayDemo {
   private DisplayDemo view;  // transaction result will be added in view 
   //getter and setter of view 
   @JsonUnwrapped
   public DisplayDemo getView() {
    return view;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice but you can use @JsonUnwrapped on variable like as bellow

```
public class DisplayDemo {

@JsonUnwrapped
   private DisplayDemo view;  // transaction result will be added in view 
   //getter and setter of view 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html).

```java
public class DisplayDemo {

   @JsonValue
   private DisplayDemo view;  // transaction result will be added in view 
   //getter and setter of view 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need view in the response.
Change your return type directly to Transaction. remove view as a return type.

```
public class DisplayTransaction {
   private List<Transaction> transation; 
   //getter and setter of transation
}
```

Use this method to return the json response.